# How to use ArcGIS to reverse geocode and get road segment number?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, java, geocoding, mxd, reverse-geocoding

I am now in a project which need to make reverse geocoding , namely ,given the latitude and longitude(assumed that the location is in a street), I want to get the road segment it is located in. What I want is not the road name ,but a road segment Id wich　is a unique identifier of the **road segment**. As we all know , a road will always consist of several road segments .What I want is the road segment Id, not the road ID, road Id is too coarse for me .So , anybody can give me some suggestions?I am now have the road grid data,including a mxd file and the data files.And I have already installed a arcGIS client and import my data to in(illustrated in the screenshot).Because my project is a java application project, it will be very good if these exists a java api for me to call directly.
[image]